# Why is my cooldown sending even when there is no cooldown? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am attempting to create a cooldown for one of my commands.

(The command)

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
async def balance(ctx):

    await load_jsons(ctx)

    coins = users_w[str(user.id)]["wallet"]

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{user.name}'s Current Balance", color = discord.Color.dark_gold())
    em.add_field(name = "Coins:", value = coins)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

    await close_jsons(ctx)
```

My issue is that the cooldown text is sent right after the message despite the command not being sent twice.

(The command error event)

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.channel.send(f"This command is on cooldown, you can use it in {round(error.retry_after, 2)} seconds.")
    else:
        return
```

Extra information you may need:

(Opens json files for use)

```
async def load_jsons(ctx):
    await open_inventory(ctx.author)
    await open_factories(ctx.author)
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    global users_i
    users_i = await get_inv_data()
    global users_w
    users_w = await get_bank_data()
    global users_f
    users_f = await get_fact_data()

    global user
    user = ctx.author

    print(f"Opened jsons for {ctx.author.name}.")
```

(Closes json files and saves them)

```
async def close_jsons(ctx):
    with open("factorydata.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users_f, f)
    with open("inv.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users_i, f)
    with open("wallet.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users_w, f)
```

(Imports)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import random

import math

import json

from urllib import parse, request
import re

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
```

Example of the issue:

> User's Current Balance

> Coins:
> 689

> This command is on cooldown, you can use it in 5.0 seconds.

**If you need any more information about the program please let me know!**

Comment: So it seems like that cooldown is bypassed and user can use the command without any kind of cooldown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was not in the code listed.

on_message() really likes to break things and there is more information on the FAQ (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)